# Communicate back to Laravel via Queue from Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, lumen

I have Lumen setup for a Private API. Laravel internally makes an API request to Lumen and then Lumen will queue a job (Amazon SQS).

How would you respond back to Laravel when the queue job has been completed or failed? If the queue worker is unable to communicate back to Laravel app for whatever reason, it will need to try again later somehow.

I have attached the system architecture diagram. My question is about the red dotted line as you can you see.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a new job called `NotifyLaravel` with any paramaters you need (Job ID, Task ID, User ID, etc).

Once your Job in the queue is done, you can `dispatch(new NotifyLaravel($jobId))` right after it's done.

The job of this job (pun intended) is to simply ping Laravel to indicate that the Queue has finished running this specific job. I won't give an example implementation, but basically you can create a shared secret between Lumen and Laravel to "authenticate" the request. Lumen then simply sends the Job ID or the identifier you use to track them.

If your Laravel instance is offline, you can simply throw an exception. The queue worker will retry later. The latter is explained in the documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#job-expirations-and-timeouts).

Comment: @Feilx Thank you for answer, I have thought about that. What do you think about using pusher.com?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Pusher dot com is used to notify clients in real time using channels, over WebSocket, iOS push functionality and Google Push functionality. It's not meant for your current use case. The most optimized thing you can do is what I wrote in my answer, where your Lumen API sends a JSON payload to a private endpoint on Laravel.

Comment: Also just to specify; the job you are creating (`NotifyLaravel`) is to be created on the lumen side